# SharePoint Search rest api search query in specific folder for document

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-search

When we are trying to perform search through SharePoint API as below:

```
RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(jsonExtendedAttrs,
                headers, HttpMethod.GET,
                this.tokenHelper.getSharepointSiteUrl("/_api/search/query?querytext='title:Document*+site:'https://esab.sharepoint.com/sites/ESABSEA/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FESABSEA%2FShared%20Documents%2FManuals&viewid=7f2484b4%2D5e97%2D4e07%2D88e7%2Da054edeac530''")
);
```

We are getting below error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)."
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:660)
    at com.panxoloto.sharepoint.rest.PLGSharepointClientOnline.getFolderAndFilesByRelativeUrl(PLGSharepointClientOnline.java:401)
    at TestSharepointClient.main(TestSharepointClient.java:22)
```

Also while using:

```
_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('folderRelativeUrl')?$expand=Folders,Files
```

we are getting the same above error.

Is somebody encountered the same error and has any solution to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I navigate to a folder named Manuals in the library named Documents in my SharePoint site, the URL in the browser will look something like this:

`https://robwindsortest991.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FDemo%2FShared%20Documents%2FManuals&viewid=363bb952...`

That's the URL used to view the folder, but it's not the URL used to identify the folder. The URL used to identify the folder looks like this:

`https://robwindsortest991.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo/Shared%20Documents/Manuals`

We can confirm this using a REST API request for the folder.

[image: Fiddler Trace]

The URL that identifies the folder is the URL for the library plus the path to the folder. In this case the path to the folder is `/Manuals`. If the Manuals folder had a sub-folder named Procedures, the path to it would be `/Manuals/Procedures`.

So changing your REST API request URL to `"/_api/search/query?querytext='title:Document*+site:'https://esab.sharepoint.com/sites/ESABSEA/Shared%20Documents/Manuals'` should give you the result you're looking for.